# How do i convert a modified list of The Alphabet into a number?

Tags: python, list, numpy

i want to convert the sentence from variable (salam) into numbers. The conversion table is like a modified alphabet just like in (char2).
My expected output is a 3x3 matrix, inside is the converted number from(salam) using (char2)

```
salam = "APAKABARBROOOOO"
salam = salam.lower
output = []
char2 = [' ','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l',
               'm','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','.',',']
i = 0
while i <= 15:
    np.array(char2.index(salam[i]))
    i = i+1
```

and the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dragg\testing funtction losaot[sn[ga\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    np.array(char2.index(salam[i]))
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

here is the image for clarity
[image]

Comment: What are you hoping *np.array()* is going to do ? Also, a 3x3 matrix has 9 elements. Your string has 15 characters. Please show expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from `salam.lower`. It should be `salam.lower()`.
Without the () you are just referencing the .lower object.